# Adding Bootstrap Styling to an existing project in RubyMine

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, rubymine

How do you install and use `Bootstrap` in a `RubyMine` project?

I do not want to use a CDN, but rather install the stylesheet into the project directory to use locally.

Comment: I haven't used RubyMine, but I've used JetBrains products a lot. Can't you just download the files here: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/ then extract the css and js files and then drag them into your css/ js folders in your project directory?

Comment: Bootstrap itself is just a css and javascript file. It doesn't actually need any 'installation' per se.

Comment: The easy way is to use one of the gems like `twitter-bootstrap-rails` or `bootstrap-sass`.

Comment: Just add `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` in your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

I used the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem by adding it to my `Gemfile` then running `bundle install` to install the new gem.